# Vue.js routing, template from server

Tags: vue.js

Как загрузить шаблон динамически, с сервера?
Я не могу вкурить маршрутизатор vue.js.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Я хочу при инициализации, загружать шаблон соответствующий url-запросу.

```js
var easy = new Vue({
    el: '#easy',
    template: '<router-view></router-view>',
    created: function () {
        this.load_static();
    },
    data: {
        current_route:       window.location.pathname,
        current_template:    '',
    }
    computed: {
        view_component () {
            return this.$http.get(this.current_route+'?ajax=true',false,{'emulateJSON': false});
        }
    },
    render (h) {
        this.current_template = '';
        var count = 0;

        this.view_component.then( response => {
                this.current_template = response.body;
        });
        while(!this.current_template && count < 100)
        {
            console.log(this.current_template);
            count++;
        }
        console.log(this.current_template);
        //return h({'template':template});
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     </head>
  <body>
   <div  id="easy">
    <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы webpack используете, то можно очень просто сделать ленивую загрузку: [lazy-loading](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Всё, что требуется — определить компоненты путей как асинхронные:

```
const Foo = resolve => {
  // `require.ensure` — это специальный синтаксис Webpack'а для определения точки разделения кода.
  require.ensure(['./Foo.vue'], () => {
    resolve(require('./Foo.vue'))
  })
}
```

Можно также упростить запись, используя альтернативный синтаксис разделения кода AMD:

```
const Foo = resolve => require(['./Foo.vue'], resolve)
```

В конфигурации путей ничего менять не нужно, просто используйте Foo как обычно:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
  ]
})
```

Comment: я не использую webpack, я просто подключил js-скрипты vue.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно, Vue.js не умеет рендерить шаблон "на горячую" (умеет конечно, через createElement, но это другая история). Так как вы хотите сделать, сделать не получиться.. Нужно уже иметь шаблон с внедренным в него vue-кодом и с помощью vue.js - запрашивать данные (json например) и перерисовывать их.. То есть шаблон должен быть, а vue.js меняет только данные (или скрывает/отображает элементы шаблона)